# PyQt widget seems to "forget" its parent

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, parent-child, pyqt5

I have a strange issue when adding a widget to a PyQt5 application.

The following is the actual code, stripped off of everything that doesn't seem related (like translateUI):

```py
class OllRoot(preferences.Group):
    """Basic openLilyLib installation"""
    def __init__(self, page):
        super(OllRoot, self).__init__(page)
        self.setParent(page)
        self.changedRoot()

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.directory = widgets.urlrequester.UrlRequester()
        self.directory.changed.connect(self.changedRoot)

        layout.addWidget(self.directory, 0, 1)

    def changedRoot(self):
        print("Self:", self)
        print("Parent:", self.parent())
        self.parent().changed.emit()
        # TODO: Check for proper openLilyLib installation
```

When the constructor is called, `parent()` is correctly set to the object that has been passed in as `page`, so the two proper objects are printed.

```
Self: <preferences.openlilylib.OllRoot object at 0x7f855a1de288>
Parent: <preferences.openlilylib.OpenLilyLibPrefs object at 0x7f855a1bcb88>
```

However, when I make a change in the `self.directory` widget `changedRoot` is called again (as I've connected it), but now the parent seems to have disappeared:

```
Self: <preferences.openlilylib.OllRoot object at 0x7f855a1de288>
Parent: <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x7f855a1dbc18>
```

**Question:**

- Am I doing anything wrong with the `setParent`?
- Am I doing anything wrong with the `connect`?
- Does the object somehow "forget" its parent?

PS: A comparable file which served as a model can be found here: https://github.com/wbsoft/frescobaldi/blob/master/frescobaldi_app/preferences/general.py#L56.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a widget is added to a layout, Qt will automatically re-parent it so that it becomes a child of the widget the layout is set on. Calling `setParent` (with a different widget) in `__init__` will have no lasting effect.

- See: [Tips for Using Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts) in the [Layout Management Overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I solved the situation by adding a new `page` property in the `__init__` method, which will *not* be hijacked by Qt's handling.